# arraylist cannot find symbol: method addLast

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with using the addLast method after declaring an ArrayList.  Here's the class code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Neuron{

        public int m_numInputs;
        public ArrayList<Double> m_vecWeight = new ArrayList<Double>();

        public Neuron(int numInputs){
                this.m_numInputs = numInputs + 1;

                //additional weight for bias
                for(int i = 0; i < numInputs + 1; ++i){
                        Random rand = new Random();
                        m_vecWeight.addLast(rand.nextFloat() * 2.0 - 1.0);

                }
        }

}
```

So the error I'm getting is:

```
cannot find symbol: method addLast(double), location: variable m_vecWeight of type ArrayList<Double>
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `addLast()` method exists in the `LinkedList` class, not in `ArrayList`. You can either:

1. Switch to use a `LinkedList` or
2. Simply call `add()`.

As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#addLast%28E%29), `addLast()` is equivalent to `add()`.

Answer (score 4):

Java [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) don't have `addLast()` method.

Use [`add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) method from `ArrayList` to add in a specified index or use [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) which has [`addLast()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#addLast%28E%29) method.

> Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
>
> This method is equivalent to `add(E)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `add()` method to add the element in the arraylist

change  `m_vecWeight.addLast(rand.nextFloat() * 2.0 - 1.0);` to

```
 m_vecWeight.add(rand.nextFloat() * 2.0 - 1.0);
```